# Unity - Change Text UI alpha color from script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text, colors

Newbie here. So i want to be able to make a fade in / out of some text elements from a gameManager script. I tried

```
public float fadeTime = 0.1f;
public Text example;


void FadeOut()
{
    example.color.a -= fadeTime;
}
```

But it gives me errors

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Remember to use  ' using UnityEngine.UI; '

Comment: "Cannot modify the return value of 'Graphic.color' because it is not a variable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Lerp. As long as you set the 'alpha' of 'newColor' to 0, text will fade out.

```
 public Text example;
 public Color newColor;
 public float fadeTime = 0.1f; //maybe rename this to fadeSpeed

 //this should be called somewhere in Update
 void FadeOut()
 {
    example.color = Color.Lerp(example.color, newColor, fadeTime * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```

EDIT: Using coroutines

```
void CallingMethod()
{
    StartCoroutine(FadeOut());
}

//note the change from 'void' to 'IEnumerator'
IEnumerator FadeOut()
{
    //ugly while, Update would be ideal
    while (example.color.a > 0)
    {
        example.color = Color.Lerp(example.color, newColor, fadeTime * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
    //code after fading is finished
}
```

Comment: I can't put it in Update() because it has to be integrated in a GetInput() method. I tried changing it with a for statement, but it doesnt work.           for(fadeTime =1; fadeTime <=0; fadeTime = fadeTime - 0.1f)                                  { example.color = Color.Lerp(example.color, newColor, fadeTime * Time.deltaTime); }

Comment: The other way to control time when Update can't be used are Coroutines. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks man, it works, although i'm confused as to why the opacity changes even tho the fadeTime remains constant, isn't lerp supposed to transform it to what fadeTime shows, and so we had to increment fadeTime?

Comment: Lerp transforms the value in the first parameter (the color of your text) to the one in the second parameter (newColor) smoothly (not instantly). FadeTime is only the speed rate at which this is happening.

Read this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html and research more about Lerp. You'll get it soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly modify color values. Instead try creating a seperate color variable and modifying it as you like.

```
Color color = example.color;
color.a -= fadeTime;
example.color = color.a;
```

If you want to fade out an object smoothly, consider using [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).